# Send attachment gmail api with Flutter

Tags: flutter, gmail-api, email-attachments

I managed sending email via gmail Api, but could you help me how to send attachment?

```
var encodedSubject = base64Url.encode(utf8.encode(subject));
subject = '=?utf-8?B?$encodedSubject?=';
var content =
        '''Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\nto: ${recipients[0]}\nsender: $userId\nsubject: $subject\n\n$body''';
    var encodedJson =
        json.encode({'raw': base64Url.encode(utf8.encode(content))});

String url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/' +
        userId +
        '/messages/send';

final http.Response response =
        await http.post(url, headers: header, body: encodedJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you to take a look at the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) and more specifically at the part of [Creating messages with attachments](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages_with_attachments):

> Creating a message with an attachment is like creating any other message, but the process of uploading the file as a multi-part MIME message depends on the programming language.

Also there is a whole section just describing the necessary request (without libraries) [to upload attachments](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads), there are multiple ways you can do this depending on your file or expected output.

Also it may be useful to take a look at the [`mime` repository](https://pub.dev/packages/mime) for mime multipart handling in dart.

Comment: The main problem that I cannot find any relevant info about how to set the content.

Comment: What do you mean by set the content? There is a link describing how you need to upload the attachment if that's what you mean.